# SQL-Doesn't return a value when the columns are multiplied

Tags: sql, multiplication

I have 3 columns in my db table, I need to multiply column, itm_count & itm_price and output the total for a given id(itm_id).

```
SELECT sum(itm_price * itm_count) as total FROM ods_temporder WHERE itm_id='11'
```

I tried to do this using the above sql query, but the result was null. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Sample data and expected results, and give us real sample data.  That always helps us.

Comment: @pier - Please update with what the actual solution was and post it either as an answer or as an edit to your question, so that future stack-overflow-farers can learn what can happen.  Right now the solution is buried in gbn's answer's comments.

Comment: Or make gbn's answer accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do this give you?

```
SELECT itm_price, itm_count FROM ods_temporder WHERE itm_id='11'
```

Is either of `itm_price` or `itm_count` NULL? Do you have rows for `itm_id` = 11?

Comment: @gbn-I made a stupid mistake, there's no column named itm_id. Thanks for pointing it out. When I changed it, the sql query worked fine. thnx

Comment: Shouldn't you have received a syntax error of sorts then? Unless you were doing this through a front end which isn't properly catching errors.

Comment: @Tom H.- Yes, I first tested it using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(itm_price, 0) * COALESCE(itm_count, 0)) as total 
  FROM ods_temporder 
 WHERE itm_id='11'
```

COALESCE is an ANSI standard for dealing with NULL values - if `itm_price` or `itm_count` is null, zero will be used in this case as the value.  Otherwise, either you don't have a row with a value of 11 for the `itm_id` column, or you're looking for the 11 value in the wrong column.

Comment: @OMG Ponies-:) Thanks that term was helpful.

Comment: If you want to set the default value to 1 then use `COALESCE(itm_count, 1).`

Answer (score 0):

What does itm_price and itm_count contain when itm_id= 11?
Is this SQL Server?  If so you can use ISNULL to handle whether itm_price or itm_count is null

Comment: Use COALESCE() instead of ISNULL(). It's ANSI standard, so works with other vendors as well. Syntax and semantics are identical, so there's no reason to keep using ISNULL().